# DateTime.toString not accounting for PM correctly from "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" to "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"

Tags: c#, date, datetime, date-parsing

I am hitting a bit of a wall with this one.

I am currently trying to capture a `DateTime` in the format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` as a string for an API call. However my original timestamp is currently formatted as a string like `dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`.

My code is as follows:

```
string startingTimestamp = "04/28/2020 11:25:43 PM"

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(startingTimestamp, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string finalTimestamp = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

What I would have expected to come out would be: `2020-04-28T23:25:43.511Z`

But instead, I get: `2020-04-28T11:25:43.000Z`.

In my debugging, I can see that the `DateTime` accounts for the PM, but it still outputs as 11:25 and not 23:25.

Am I missing some extra step to hard convert the `DateTime` to be 24H instead of 12H or is the toString method not the appropriate choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try HH for 24 hour. Use hh for 12 hour.

Comment: I knew I was missing some weird syntax rule. Worked like a charm!